# .NET Capitalization Rules for Identifiers and property System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

Why is the name of the property `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` all uppercase? According to [Capitalization Rules for Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0) and the fact that UTF is an acronym longer than 2 characters the property should be named `System.Text.Encoding.Utf8` or am I wrong?

Comment: I think the simple reason is that not everyone is always aware of all the rules, or perhaps the decision was made before the rules were written down.

Comment: maybe to offer one more selling point for intellisense! or more likely because that is how it is conventionally written being a unicode notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all uppercase because it was authored that way.

The design and implementation of .NET 1.0 (and `Encoding.UTF8` goes all the way back to there) well precedes the Framework Design Guidelines in their current form, let alone their enforcement. As a result, you can find plenty of violations in the framework of those guidelines. A small sample:

- `System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider` (and plenty of other classes in `System.Security.Cryptography`)
- `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding`
- `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`

And a systematic search would probably show up many more.

This isn't as silly as it looks: the whole reason people come up with guidelines in the first place is because they notice inconsistencies like this, and then sit down and come up with a set of rules that best reflects current practices. Going back to change capitalization on current classes (and breaking existing software in the process) isn't worth it, however.

Comment: And for new classes it's recommended to follow the guidelines even if the correct names like `Utf8` or `Ascii` look strange next to the incorrect ones?

Comment: @RadekMicek: "Looking strange" is not something you can formalize, so yes. There is no compelling reason to spell `ASCII` in your own classes just because there also exists an `ASCIIEncoding` class in the framework. Imagine how inconvenient it would be if someone had to track all the exceptions -- for *any* class you want to create you'd have to check the framework first! Now, if you are the one adding a new class to the existing `System.Text` namespace things might be different -- consistency might trump formality then. But that's within a namespace. (I don't know Microsoft's local policies.)